# CollapsingToolbarLayout in API 21

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

If you take a look at the CheeseDetailActivity in the [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) app, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` seems to cause the `Toolbar` to be misaligned on API 21:

[image: misaligned]

This also causes the `Toolbar` to be obscured after scrolling down:

[image]

Presumably, it should look like this (API 18 screenshot):

[image]

Has anyone encountered this or know of a solution to get the toolbar to align correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the v21 theme changes to include:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

The margin needs to be modified on the toolbar for v21 to account for the space that the system bar takes.

dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="action_bar_margin_top">0dp</dimen>
```

dimens.xml (v21)

```
<dimen name="action_bar_margin_top">-24dp</dimen>
```

Add margin and fitsSystemWindows to the `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_margin_top"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```